# How to make Humanizer not display "no time" if the precision is bigger?

Tags: c#, humanizer

I am using [Humanizer on a TimeSpan](https://github.com/MehdiK/Humanizer#humanize-timespan) with precision 4:

```
(dateEnd - dateStart).Humanize(4)
```

And it generates something like this:

```
2 hours, 17 minutes, 20 seconds, 141 milliseconds
```

But when the time remaining is just minutes (less than a hour left) it generates:

```
17 minutes, 20 seconds, 141 milliseconds, no time
```

Is there a way to not include this "no time"?

Answer (score 4):

I'm doing this to change the precision based on the run time length:

```
TimeSpan runTime = dateEnd - dateStart;

if (runTime.TotalMinutes < 1)
{
    precision = 1; //49 seconds
}
else if (runTime.TotalHours < 1)
{
    precision = 2; //27 minutes, 49 seconds
}
else
{
    precision = 3; //1 day, 2 hours, 27 minutes  OR  2 hours, 27 minutes, 49 seconds
}

runTime.Humanize(precision);
```